# Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem Counterexample

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I am trying to come up with a counterexample to this theorem under the assumption that the space is not sigma finite.  I tried working with the power set of the real numbers with the measure $\mu(A) = \sum_{a\in A} \lambda(a)$, where $a\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $A\subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.

Specifically the theorem states:

Suppose  $T:(X,\mathcal{B},m)\to (X,\mathcal{B},m)$ is measure-preserving and $f\in L^1(m)$. Then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(T^i(x))$$

converges a.e. to a  function $g\in L^1(m)$.

Comment: Why do you believe there is a counterexample? The theorem is about one $L^1$-function at a time, and for any $L^1$-function $f \colon X\rightarrow {\mathbf R}$ the set $\{x \in X : f(x) \not= 0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite, so also $\{x \in X : f(T^ix) \not= 0 \text{ for some } i\}$ is $\sigma$-finite. Thus off a $\sigma$-finite subset of $X$ that pointwise average you write down is $0$, hence you may as well assume $X$ is $\sigma$-finite in the proof of the ergodic theorem (for an *individual* $L^1$-function).